# How to create a class instance using the CLI in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, oop, readline

Is it possible to create a class instance using the Command Line/CLI in TypeScript?

```
// Machine.ts
export class Machine {
    public model: string;
    public height: number;
    public width: number;

    constructor(model: string, height: number, width: number) {
        this.model = model;
        this.height = height;        
        this.width = width
    }
}
```

```
// index.ts
export function start(): void {
    clear();
    print('Welcome to Machine!');
    askQuestion(`What is the model, height, and width of your machine?`, functionThatCreatesClassInstance); 
}
```

I would like the user input to create something like this:

```
const machine = new Machine(Xerox, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use promptly
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promptly

```
import * as promptly from 'promptly';

const userInput = await promptly.prompt('');
```